# Why is this XPath query failing? Have I made a mistake with DOMXPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

This question is a bit complicated, as there are alot of moving parts, but I'll try to minify and use only the most relevant snippets.

I'm working on an XML/XHTML document parser based on the `DOM` classes in PHP, but it appears that the part that makes use of `DOMXPath` is failing. Given this example document:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:zuq="http://localhost/~/zuqml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="pageHeading">
        <zuq:data name="pageHeading" />
    </h1>
    <p id="pageDescription">
        <zuq:data name="pageDescription">
            <zuq:format type="trim">
                <zuq:param name="length">300</zuq:param>
                <zuq:param name="append">...</zuq:param>
            </zuq:format>
        </zuq:data>
    </p>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <zuq:region name="toolbar" />
    </div>
    <div id="postWrap">
        <zuq:region name="post">
            <div class="post">
                <img height="200" width="200">
                    <zuq:attr name="src">
                        ./src/<zuq:data name="postImageSrc" />
                    </zuq:attr>
                </img>
                <h2><zuq:data name="postHeading" /></h2>
                <p>
                    <zuq:data name="postBody">
                        <zuq:format type="trim">
                            <zuq:param name="length">300</zuq:param>
                            <zuq:param name="append">
                                <a>
                                    <zuq:attr name="href">
                                        ./?postId=<zuq:data name="postId" />
                                    </zuq:attr>
                                    More »
                                </a>
                            </zuq:param>
                        </zuq:format>
                    </zuq:data>
                </p>
            </div>
        </zuq:region>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created a parser that takes a `DataObject` object (which is essentially just a fancy tree of other `DataObject` objects) and loops through parsing documents using data in the tree. The document source paths are also stored in the tree.

The parser constructor:

```
public function __construct(DataObject $dataObject){
    $this->_dataObject = $dataObject;
}
```

The public `render` method, called to return the document as a string:

```
public function render($filename = null){
    $document = new DOMDocument;
    $frag = $this->_build($document, $this->_dataObject);
    if(is_null($filename)){
        return $document->saveXML($frag);
    }else{
        //render to file
    }
}
```

And finally the private `_build` method, where the meat of the action is happening:

```
protected function _build(DOMNode $node, DataObject $dataObject){
    $ownerDocument = $node instanceof DOMDocument
        ? $node
        : $node->ownerDocument;

    $buffer = $ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();    

    for($dataIndex = 0; $dataIndex < $dataObject->count(); $dataIndex++){

        $frag = $ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
        if(!$dataObject->hasParent() || ($dataObject->getFilename() != $dataObject->getParent()->getFilename())){
            $frag->appendXML(file_get_contents($dataObject->getFilename()));
        }else{
            foreach($node->childNodes as $child){
                $frag->appendChild($child->cloneNode(true));
            }
        }
        $frag->normalize();

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($ownerDocument);
        $xpath->registerNamespace('zuq', $ownerDocument->lookupNamespaceURI('zuq'));

        //THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLES ARE
        $nodeList = $xpath->query('.//zuq:data[not(ancestor::zuq:region)]', $frag);

        for($nodeIndex = $nodeList->length - 1; $nodeIndex >= 0; $nodeIndex--){

            //PERFORM REPLACEMENTS

        }
        $buffer->appendChild($frag);
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

I understand that's quite a chunk, but if there's a problem, it has to be somewhere in there. **The problem is that the XPath query is *not returning any nodes*. I've tested it on documents outright, and it works fine. It finds all `<zuq:data />` elements that are outside of any `<zuq:region />` elements, within the context of the given node (which in recursion be the regions, but I'm not there yet) which will allow parsing each region level individually.**

When I use `$nodeList = $xpath->query('.//*', $frag);` and loop through the resulting `$nodeList`, it has all of the document elements, from `<html>` through to the most nested.

Why is my `$nodeList = $xpath->query('.//zuq:data[not(ancestor::zuq:region)]', $frag);` query is failing? I really hope that it's a simple matter of, "Oh, you just forgot to *_*_."

In advance, I really appreciate any help, and if more details are necessary, I'd be happy to provide, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> query is failing? I really hope that
>   it's a simple matter of, "Oh, you just
>   forgot to __."

I think that it is like that. Use a static URI `'http://localhost/~/zuqml'` better than that `$ownerDocument->lookupNamespaceURI('zuq')`

Comment: Outstanding **Alejandro**; That seems to have done the trick. Any idea as to why the lookup is failing? Probably because there are no namespaces actually registered to the document object, since the parser makes use of `DOMDocumentFragments` to manage regions of the document. I'm curious because I keep moving files around on my server and want to ensure that documents can be validated.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Besides the reason why `lookupNamespaceURI()` is not working as it suppose to do, namespace URI should be statics URI known in advance and prefix shouldn't be used as synonym. Remember that you can register `other` prefix for `http://localhost/~/zuqml` URI and still select `zuq:data` elements with `other:data` QName test.